# URL path is being repeated ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am in `https://localhost:44311/` and I have those 2 buttons

[image]

When I press the Customers button I want to go to `https://localhost:44311/Customers` and see a list of the current Customers. Similarly `https://localhost:44311/Movies` and see a list of movies.
For those two I have two Controllers, named `MoviesController` and `CustomersController`.
This is my code in `CustomersController`:

```
 namespace MovieLab.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult AllCustomers()
        {
            var customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer(){ Name = "Customer 1"},
                new Customer(){ Name = "Customer 2" }
            };

            var customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel()
            {
                Customers = customers
            };

            return View(customerViewModel);
        }
}
```

when I build the code above, my URL looks like this `https://localhost:44311/Customers/AllCustomers`
shouldn't it be `https://localhost:44311/AllCustomers`? (I named it **AllCustomers** so the URL doesn't look like **Customers/Customers**)

Comment: No, the route works as expected. You shouldn't use the name `AllCustomers` in the first place. The default route convention is to return all customers through `Customers/` and specific customers by ID using `Customers/123`. That's how REST routes are expected to look. Rename your method to `Get()` to return all customers and add `Get(int id)` to get a single customer by id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Default` route in `RouteConfig.cs` looks like this:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

This will generate a url like:

```
https://localhost:44311/Customers/AllCustomers
```

Now to generate your required url, you need to set the route as (add it before the default one):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyRoute",
    url: "allcustomers",
    defaults: new { controller= "Customers", action = "AllCustomers", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// default route
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} );
```

Comment: By doing that im getting an HTTP 404, and the requested URL is `/Customers/AllCustomers` . I have a `.cshtml` file for the navigation bar with two `@html.ActionLink("Customers", "AllCustomers", "Customers")` and 1 more for the movies, does that affect the result? @Rahul

Comment: @Ntavass Try the above route in my updated answer

Comment: That did the trick thank you very much! @Rahul